# Layout design is different on android mobiles and emulator

Tags: android

I have designed android app and I when I open the app in emulator and mobile phone the designs are very bad, the buttons and images overlapped in design and it's very bad, how can i make it plz ??

here is the design in android studio

[image]

here is the activity in BlueStacks

[image]

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="385dp"
    android:layout_height="510dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="bishoy.homeactivity.Main2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Christianity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="?attr/actionModeSplitBackground"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/abomaar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="289dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/anba"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="289dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/quots"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="209dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/jesus"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Top right corner... `9+` in red... You have layout errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your views have absolute positions

```
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="xdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="ydp"
```

that's why they are displayed on that specific location on layout. I suggest you add constraints to your view to allow them to position relative to other views or the parent. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) out

Comment: More specifically: those positions only are displayed in the preview, not the actual app

Comment: sry , u mean to add ( AbsoluteX,Y ) in Images ? or Add Constraint Layout before each image ?

Comment: Just add constraint to every view. You can do it graphically in the layout editor. Just hover at the edges of you view and anchor it to a nearby view or parent. This will fix its position relative to it.

Comment: thanks alot , i will check it and tell u the update , thx again

Answer (score 0):

Some of your views don't have constraints, so they show up at the initial position (although these views are displayed correctly in the android studio layout editor because of tools attribute). Click on the red exclamation icon at the top right of layout editor to figure out more.